# How to switch Vnet of a Azure VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-network

As per our requirement, we have created two Vnets in Azure. The Vnets are connected to each other by virtual network gateway. They can communicate with each other. One Vnet is assigned to a VM. We need to switch the Vnet of the VM to another one.
How do we do that without deallocating or deleting-recreating the VM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately creating an image and then deleting and recreating the VM is the only supported way of getting your VM image to a different virtual network.

[This documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-vm) describes the limitations on virtual machines in relation to network interfaces. It states NICs on VMs should all be in the same virtual network. So from that we can conclude that there is no way to do this without recreating the VM.